Failed to delete backend Firebase App Hosting (new)
I have created several backends with Firebase AppHosting (the new feature from Firebase). I would like to delete some of them.
Following the cli help, I applied the following command:
firebase:apphosting:backends:delete -l us-central1 -s my-backend-id

However, it keeps returning:

Failed to delete backend: my-backend-id. Please check the parameters you have provided.

Both parameters are correct as it confirms from the list that this backend is present.
I also went to Cloud Run and manually deleted the backends, but this did not work either, the backends are still visible in my Firebase Console.
Is this an issue as its a public preview, or am I doing smth wrong?

Update: after upgrading my firebase-tools to 3.11.2 I managed to delete the backends (on Firebase console not visible anymore). The error message as described above keeps still occurring though. I suspect its therefore related to the fact that App Hosting is still in Public Preview.

This command worked for me:
firebase apphosting:backends:delete -l us-central1 my-backened-id 

This worked indeed, after also upgrading firebase-tools to minimum 3.11.2. Received btw answer from Firebase Support that there were indeed issues, that are in the process of being resolved.

According to  the latest documentation, the command OP posted is missing the <PROJECT-ID>
Delete a backend
To fully remove a backend, first use the Firebase CLI and then manually remove related assets, taking special care not to delete any resources that might be used by other backends or other aspects of your Firebase project.

Run the following command to delete the App Hosting Backend. This disables all domains for your backend and deletes the associated Cloud Run service:

firebase apphosting:backends:delete <BACKEND-ID> --project <PROJECT-ID> --location us-central1


(Optional) In the Google Cloud Console tab for Artifact Registry, delete the image for your backend in "firebaseapphosting-images".

In Cloud Secret Manager, delete any secrets with "apphosting" in the secret name, taking special care to make sure these secrets are not used by other backends or other aspects of your Firebase project.



It may be broken (Oct, 2024)
Delete seems broken (in my project anyways).
⚠  You are about to permanently delete this backend:
┌──────────────┬──────────────┬───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┬─────────────┬─────────────────────┐
│ Backend      │ Repository   │ URL                                                       │ Location    │ Updated Date        │
├──────────────┼──────────────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────┼─────────────────────┤
│ <BACKEND-ID> │ <PROJECT-ID> │ https://<BACKEND-ID>--<PROJECT-ID>.us-central1.hosted.app │ us-central1 │ 2024-10-10 16:26:53 │
└──────────────┴──────────────┴───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┴─────────────┴─────────────────────┘
Are you sure? Yes
⠹ Deleting backend...

Error: Failed to delete backend: <BACKEND-ID>.


Updated my firebase tools and then it worked npm update -g firebase-tools
